# How can I change initial view controller after first launch?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that contains a tutorial, which I only want to display as the initial view the first time the app is opened. After that, I want to present my main view controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after your app lauch, it will call the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the app delegate:

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // here you have the chance to change your rootview controller
    if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "notFirstInApp") == false){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "notFirstInApp")
        window?.rootViewController = your tutorial view controller
    }else{
        window?.rootViewController = your main viewcontroller
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Uprooted. I'd only add that you might want to provide a way to view the tutorial a second time. Many user may appreciated that.

Answer (score 0):

if you like to segue or navigate the view just use

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "youSegueIdentifire"
    {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? OtherViewController {
            destinationVC.numberToDisplay = counter
        }
    }
}
```

and call this segue

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("youSegueIdentifire", sender: self)
```

and if you like to change the root view as you are talking initial viewcontroller

```
var exampleViewController: ExampleViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExampleController") as! ExampleViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController
```